# JAR does not have write permissions in its own install directoy (Windows 8)

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions, installation

I have built a Java application, made a self-contained application out of it and made an installer with InnoSetup.

When I install it, my app will be installed to the default path on Windows 8:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallDirOfApp`.

When I start my app there it has to write some files (e.g. settings) to its install directory. But it does not have the permission to do that. Only when I start it with 'Start as administrator' it works well again.

How can I fix it? I don't want to tell my users they always have to click 'execute as admin'.

And by the way: Why does Windows not allow an application to write into its own installation directory anyway?

Comment: "When I start my app there it has to write some files (e.g. settings) to it's install directory." Don't do that, basically. Life is much simpler if you separate the data which is inherent to the program itself (its binaries and resources) from generated data (settings, user documents etc). It makes things like upgrading much easier, as you know you can replace *everything* in the Program Files area. This is very common.

Comment: Place you programs writable data into either `{user.home}/AppData/Local` or `{user.home}/AppData/Roaming` depending on if the configuration is transferable to other machines or not

Comment: I think the real question is: why do **you** think that a directory that is used for installing applications is an appropriate place to store the data that application itself is dealing with?!

Comment: Thank you all very much. I just always wanted to keep data and application together because it seemed cleaner for me. But than I will retreat to public opinion ;)

Comment: Thats a good question. The problem is what if you ask the user through the app where he wants to generate "report xyz", if he chooses a directory then the write permission will fail (I guess) as the app is not run as an adminstrator. how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the luck of Windows 8.

How to fix it? The right answer (IMHO) is "do not write to installation directory". There is a difference between installation and working directory. You can continue using `"C\Program Files\Foobar"` as an installation directory, but use something like `"%temp%\Foobar"` or `"%home%\Foobar"` as a working directory. The locations that I recommended are typically writable.